# Spring batch Neo4j item reader

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-batch, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to read data from neo4j database using `Neo4jItemReader` in spring batch application but not able to get instance of `org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory`.
PS: I'm also using spring data neo4j in same project.

Spring Boot version: `2.6.7`

Here's what I tried

```
@Bean
fun postReader(): ItemReader<Post> {
    return Neo4jItemReaderBuilder<Post>()
        .name("postReader")
        .sessionFactory(WHERE_TO_GET_IT)
        .matchStatement("(p:Post)")
        .returnStatement("p")
        .pageSize(1000)
        .build()
}
```

Comment: With Spring Boot v2.6.7, you get SDN v6.2.4. The [documentation of v6](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/) does not seem to include a section about how to manually configure a session factory, while the docs of v5 do, see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/5.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference.getting_started.spring-configuration). That said, I added an answer with how to autowire the Session Factory auto-configured by  Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring Boot with the SDN starter, you should be able to autowire the session factory that is auto-configured by Boot:

```
@Bean
fun postReader(SessionFactory sessionFactory): ItemReader<Post> {
    return Neo4jItemReaderBuilder<Post>()
        .name("postReader")
        .sessionFactory(sessionFactory) // auto-configured by Spring Boot, autowired by Spring Framework
        .matchStatement("(p:Post)")
        .returnStatement("p")
        .pageSize(1000)
        .build()
}
```

Comment: This answer does not apply to SDN 6 (which is what i'm using) as there's no Neo4j-OGM included in SDN. Only `SessionFactory` available is `org.neo4j.driver.internal.SessionFactory` but that's not what i want.